# Pass username to Django form

Tags: python, django, forms, keyword-argument

I have a custom Form where I need to pass in the request.user.username so I can use that to fill out forms.ModelChoiceField based on what user is accessing it.

Here is what I have

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DepartmentForm(request.POST, username=request.user.username)
    # Do stuff
else:
     form = DepartmentForm(username=request.user.username)
```

forms.py

```
class DepartmentForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.username = kwargs.pop('username', None)
        super(DepartmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    Company = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Company.objects.raw('''
      SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.name, c.createdBy, c.allowedTeam_ID FROM projects_company AS c
      LEFT JOIN auth_user_groups AS aug ON c.allowedTeam_id=aug.group_id
      LEFT JOIN auth_user AS au ON aug.user_id=au.id
      WHERE au.username = %s OR c.createdBy = %s''',
     [self.username, self.username]),
     empty_label='Select company', widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'materialSelect', 'id': 'companyDropdown'}))
```

But when I try to select fill out self.username, I get:

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

I tried searching for my solution, but none of the ones I found seem to work.
I would appreciate any help you guys can give.
If you need more information, please don't hesitate to ask, and I will update the question accordingly.

This is the error I'm getting:

> line 25, in DepartmentForm
> [self.username, self.username]),
> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Which is the end of the query where I select based on self.username

Comment: Please show the code that is giving the error.

Comment: I updated the question, to show the error i'm getting, and also the line that contains the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `Company = forms.ModelChoiceField()` is evaluated when the module is loaded. You don't have access to `self.username` at that point.

Instead, you should set the `queryset` in the form's `__init__` method:

```
class DepartmentForm(forms.Form):
    company = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Company.objects.none(),  # use empty queryset now, we'll set the real queryset when the form is initialised
        widget=forms.Select(...),
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.username = kwargs.pop('username', None)
        super(DepartmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['company'].queryset = Company.objects.raw(...)
```

Comment: Ahh yeah okay that makes sense, and it works too. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-fill any field with a dictionary:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # do stuff
else:
    form = DepartmentForm({"username":request.user.username})
```

or

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # do stuff
else:
    form = DepartmentForm()
    form.initial = {"username":request.user.username}
```

Comment: So where should this be placed. Cause i added the first line right after creating the def department view. And then it complains about the same thing. If i try using username instead of self.username Its the same thing  but with username no being defined

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: So this is what i got now.
Views.py
`if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DepartmentForm(request.POST)
    # Do stuff
else:
     form = DepartmentForm()
     form.initial = {"username":request.user.username}`

But i seem to be getting the exact same error. BTW i have not changed anything in forms.py, should i?